# I want to print only the fourth number in the combination function

Tags: python, combinations

I got a code from the Internet that prints a number of combinations of all cases.
`arr = [1,2,3,4]` and `n = 4` and `r=2`
The number of cases that appear is as follows:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

I want to print only the fourth number `[2,3]` here.
Can you help me?

```
def printCombination(arr, n, r):
    data = [0] * r
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0)

def combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index, data, i):
    if (index == r):
        for j in range(r):
            print(data[j], end = " ")
        print()
        return

    if (i >= n):
        return

    data[index] = arr[i]

    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index + 1, data, i + 1)
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index, data, i + 1)

arr = [1,2,3,4]
r = 2
n = len(arr)

printCombination(arr, n, r)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text. Not as image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it's hard because i'm not used to stackoverflow yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def printCombination(arr, n, r):
    data = [0] * r
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, 0, data, 0)

def combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index, data, i):
    if (index == r):
        for j in range(r):
            if (data[0] == arr[1] and data[1] == arr[2]):
                print(data[j], end = " ")
        print()
        return

    if (i >= n):
        return

    data[index] = arr[i]

    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index + 1, data, i + 1)
    combinationUtil(arr, n, r, index, data, i + 1)

arr = [1,2,3,4]
r = 2
n = len(arr)

printCombination(arr, n, r)
```

Also, now that I think about it more clearly, I think that you can do it in a way that is much simpler. It seems that for a list that is 4 numbers long, you want to get the middle two numbers. So you could just do it like this:

```
def printMiddle(list):
    print([list[1], list[2]])

list = [1,2,3,4]
printMiddle(list)
```